# Parsing a specific date within logstash

Tags: date, logstash

I am trying to parse the following date in logstash
2019-08-01T00:00:00Z/2019-08-02T00:00:00Z

I tried multiple things but nothing worked

Option 1

```
date{
match => ["timestamp","ISO8601/ISO8601"]
    target => "timestamp"
  }
```

Option 2

```
date{
match => ["timestamp","ISO8601"]
    target => "timestamp"
  }
```

Option 3 - The pipeline works but I get dateparsefailure

```
date{
match => ["timestamp","ISO8601"/"ISO8601"]
    target => "timestamp"
  }
```

Comment: I tried the following
`date{
        match => ["timestamp", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ'/'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ" ]
        target => "timestamp"
      }`

Now I get only the last part of the date as an output 
Input   2019-08-01T00:00:00Z/2019-08-02T00:00:00Z
Output : 2019-08-02T00:00:00Z

Comment: `2019-08-01T00:00:00Z/2019-08-02T00:00:00Z` is this a date? These are two dates. How could logstash parse these to a single date field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `grok` pattern to collect the dates into separate fields and then join them using `mutate`

```
filter {  
  grok {
    match => [ "message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:date_1}/%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:date_2}" ]
    tag_on_failure => [ "_failure", "_grokparsefailure" ]
  }

  if "_failure" not in [tags] {
    mutate {
      add_field => { "timestamp" => "%{date_1}/%{date_2}"}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Very interesting. I will try this out. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Did this help? If so, can you please accept the answer?

Comment: Sorry, got derailed with other things. Will check now and confirm